# Can't figure out how to get rid of blank space at the bottom of windows console in C#

Tags: c#, console

I'm using the console for a small console game I'm creating for fun but I've run into a problem.

The console for the game is always having this consistent amount of blank lines at the end of it that just take up space. I can literally make a completely fresh project with nothing in it, run it and it gives the same blank lines. I don't know how to fix this. See image for example.

[image: Console Screen]

Comment: Can you provide the code that is writing to the console?

Comment: Console.WindowHeight = 55;
            Console.WindowWidth = 110;

Or did you mean the code that is displaying the text? The code that displays the text is just Console.WriteLine();

Comment: It literally doesn't matter what I do, it will always be like that. I can set the console size to literally anything on a completely new program that just prints hello world and it will have those weird blank lines that create blank space.

Comment: 55 lines but it literally doesn't matter it will keep doing it whether I change the size or not.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my question because I just found out more, it literally doesn't matter what I do my console will always be like that. I cannot make a minimal reproducible example because it does not matter what my code is it will always be like that. Is there any way to fix/change that?

Comment: `I cannot make a minimal reproducible example because it does not matter what my code is it will always be like that.` That argument makes no sense. Make a 20 line or so code example showing the problem, so we can download and repro at our end. Then we can try and help you.

Comment: Let me rephrase (sorry for late response I went to sleep). I think it's not a coding issue anymore, but rather my actual console. Even opening cmd from windows has these blank lines at the end. If I open the console at all it will always leave this blank space. Now, I don't know if I should be going somewhere else for this or if this is still the correct place. Just to be clear, I spent around 2 hours rewriting parts of my program to see what was causing it to leave the blank space, and posted it here, before realizing it is like that no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the scrolls and the blank space that you see in the `Console` window, you need to make the console screen buffer same as the console window size. Use the code below:

```
Console.SetBufferSize(Console.WindowWidth, Console.WindowHeight);
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to do it manually, for specific console screens such as command prompt, you can get rid of the blank space by going into properties of the window like this:
[image: Console Window]

And then navigate to the Terminal tab and check `Disable Scroll-Forward` checkbox from there.

[image: Disable Scroll-Forward]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I don't have the terminal tab (I don't know why) but after going into properties I adjusted the size because it was at 300 for some reason.

I appreciate your response.